# Third order non linear ODE with missing independent variable (also no first derivative)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE:

$$y'''y'' - \sqrt{1+y''^2}=0$$

So, I know that if there's the dependent variable "x" missing, we would use the following transformation:

$ y' = p, p=p(y) $, where $y'' = p'p$.

However, since **y'** is actually missing, I set that $ y'' = p, p=p(y)$, and therefore $y''' = p'p$.

Applying that, we get the following equation:

$$p^2p' - \sqrt{1+p^2} = 0$$ which is a separable equation with the solution $$p= \ln({\sqrt{x^2+1} +x})-\frac{x^2+1}{x}+C_1$$

But after substituting $y'' = p$ I get that I'd need to integrate two more times, and some of the integrals are not that easy to perform which leads me to think I should have taken a different route since the beginning.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? If there's no easier way to do this exercise then please tell me, or if you know a "trick" or easier transformation I'd be happy to now.

**Second question**: If $y' = p$, and $y'' = p'p$, then what is $y''' = $? I can't figure this out and whatever I do I get stuck. I understand the logic for the second derivative, but after that it gets complicated.

Comment: It would just be easier to let $p(x) = y''(x) \implies p' = y'''$ so you get $$pp' - \sqrt{1 + p^{2}} = 0$$ then separate and integrate etc.

Comment: Am I allowed to do that since the original equation does not contain the independent variable?

Comment: Why not? It's just a substitution to make the algebra easier. If you didn't want to use the substitution, just note that $y'' y''' = (y''^{2})'/2$ and so $$y'' y''' - \sqrt{1+y''^{2}} = 0 \implies \frac{1}{2} \frac{(y''^{2})'}{\sqrt{1+y''^{2}}} = 1 \implies \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d(y''^{2})}{\sqrt{1+y''^{2}}} = \int dx$$

Answer (score 1):

If you set $y''=p(y)$, then $y'''=p'(y)y'$ which can not be further rewritten. To get the usual replacement trick for the independent variable, you would have to set $y''=p(y')$, as then $y'''=p'(y')y''=p'p$.

The resulting integration is then for $y'$ as independent variable, not $x$.

---

However, one gets faster results by just integrating
$$
1=\frac{y''y'''}{\sqrt{1+y''^2}}\implies x+c=\sqrt{1+y''^2}\\~\\
y''=\pm\sqrt{1-(x+c)^2}
$$

Comment: how does integrating $\frac{y''y'''}{\sqrt{1+y''^2}}$ yield simply $sqrt{1+y''^2}$? I don't seem to understand it :(

More specifically, I fail to understand how integrating the numerator works.

Comment: Just compute the derivative. In general $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1+u(x)^2}=\frac{uu'}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$.